# Linux command get tomcat process id by name

Tags: linux, command-line

Linux command line:

When i execute the following command `ps -ef |grep tomcat` it shows me the following process

```
abcapp   28119     1  0 12:53 ?        00:00:19 /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10//bin/java -Xmx256m -Dabc.log.file=/home/app/apps/rum/logs/dev.log -Dabc.config=dev -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///home/abcapp/env/abc_env/abc_env-1.2/config/log4j-webapp.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/abcapp/env/tomcat/tomcat-5.5-26-rum/conf/logging.properties -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/abcapp/env/tomcat/tomcat-5.5-26-rum/common/endorsed -classpath :/home/abcapp/env/tomcat/tomcat-5.5-26-rum/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/abcapp/env/tomcat/tomcat-5.5-26-rum/bin/commons-logging-api.jar -Dcatalina.base=/home/abcapp/env/tomcat/tomcat-5.5-26-rum -Dcatalina.home=/home/abcapp/env/tomcat/tomcat-5.5-26-rum -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/abcapp/env/tomcat/tomcat-5.5-26-rum/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

but when i issue following command it shows nothing

```
pgrep tomcat-5.5-26-rum OR pgrep "*-rum"
```

can some body help me how can i get tomcat process id by its name regex for "*-rum"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: People seem to be stingy when it comes to upvoting questions :) Thanks for asking this, it made it easy for me to find the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

pgrep only search for the process name without the full path (in your case only *java*) and without arguments.

Since *tomcat-5.5-26-rum* is part of the latter, i'd search the pid with

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat-5.5-26-rum | grep java | awk ' { print $2 } '
```

The double grep is useful to discard the grep pids itself

Comment: If someone, like me, is looking for one line code to kill tomcat. (Assuming you have only one tomcat installed & running). It works on my Centos 7. 

`sudo /bin/kill -15 $(ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep java | awk ' { print $2 } ')`

Answer (score 7):

Just add following line at the start of `catalina.sh` file

```
CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/tomcat.pid
```

OR

```
CATALINA_PID=/tmp/tomcat.pid
```

And bounce tomcat. This will create a `tomcat.pid` file in the given path and put the Tomcat process pid in it.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

This will give the process id of current running tomcat

echo `ps aux | grep org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'`